# HTML CSS: One Bootstrap Collapsible is affecting Others on a Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I copy this code twice in a page for a Bootstrap collapsible, one toggle button will affect other toggles, causing everything to expand or collapse.

How would I resolve this issue? Each collapsible should only affects its own set.

The end goal is to have a collapsible as a shared component. So if I copy it 3,4,5, 100 times in a page, other ones should not be affected. (will be using C# extension methods later).

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Please copy code twice in a page.

```
<!--Accordion wrapper-->
<div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <div class="card">
        <!-- Card header -->
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
               aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1 <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                </h5>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Card body -->
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1"
             data-parent="#accordionEx">
            <div class="card-body">
                1111 test
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <div class="card">

        <!-- Card header -->
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseTwo2"
               aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    Collapsible Group Item #2 <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                </h5>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Card body -->
        <div id="collapseTwo2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2"
             data-parent="#accordionEx">
            <div class="card-body">
                2222 test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <div class="card">

        <!-- Card header -->
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseThree3"
               aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    Collapsible Group Item #3 <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                </h5>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Card body -->
        <div id="collapseThree3" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3"
             data-parent="#accordionEx">
            <div class="card-body">
                3333 test
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Accordion card -->
</div>
```

Looking to isolate the behavior. Would like to avoid javascript route, but if needed thats fine. Maybe something to do with everyone sharing same Id,  data-parents, etc.

Comment: Just copying these codes twice won't work, each card body should have a different `id`, and also because `id` should be unique.

Comment: where should I put the ids, and how would i create random ids?

Comment: You will have to create those cards dynamically to make their `id`s unique to each other, via php or javascript. And the one you need to edit would be the `<div id="collapseThree3"` part and `href="#collapseThree3"`

Comment: would the Id be the AccordianEx in this example, I tried changing all AccordianEx in one set  to AccordianEx2, does not work

Comment: No, change the `id` of the card body, then the `href` of the card header, they should match *(add a # prefix for the `href` before the `id` name)*. Look for the difference between the three card

Comment: actually its just all the collapseOne1, I replaced them with teststring,  it worked, thanks, feel free to write as answer and I can give points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Bootstrap's [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example), especially when you are just copying the cards, don't forget to check that the `id` of the card body **MUST** be unique and the `href` of the card header must match it.

**WRONG** *(both card body have the same `id`, which is `collapseOne`)*:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Body of Collapsible #1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Body of Collapsible #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CORRECT** *(each card body has its own `id`)*:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Body of Collapsible #1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Body of Collapsible #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```